# on the way / on one's way - what's the difference in meaning?

Tags: word-usage

> 1. I'm on the way to where you are.
> 2. I'm on my way to where you are.

What's the difference in meaning?

Answer (score 1):

There's no much difference between the two of them. However, **I am on the way** implies an established route used by many people whereas **I am on my way** refers to **my particular** route.